# DELETE 404 (Not Found) Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON Promise.then (async)

Tags: javascript, django, django-rest-framework, fetch-api

I've created an API using Django-REST-Framework. I have problem as trying to delete objects when I send DELETE request to my API. This is my backend.

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('getFavourite/', views.getFavourites),
    path('addFavourite/', views.addFavourites),
    path('deleteFavourite', views.deleteFavourites),
]
```

and this views.py

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def getFavourites(request):
    favourites=Favorite.objects.all()
    serializer=FavouriteSerializer(favourites , many=True)

    return Response(serializer.data)

@api_view(['DELETE'])
def deleteFavourites(request):
      name=request.data['name']
      favorite=Favorite.objects.get(name=name)
      favorite.delete()
      result="Your favorite has been deleted"
    
      return Response({"result":result})
```

And this is my frontend:

```js
let newContent=document.getElementById('favorite');

fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/getFavourite/")
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => {
    for(i=0; i<data.length; i++){
        newContent.innerHTML += `<div class="container">
                                     <div style="">
                                          I do ${data[i].name} every  ${data[i].timeOfDoing} days
                                          <div onclick="favDelete('${data[i].name}')" 
                                               class="deletion-sign">&#9747;</div>
                                     </div>
                                 </div>`
                                 }
                })

function favDelete(name){
    console.log(name)
    fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/deleteFavourite/" , {
        method:"DELETE",
        headers: {
            'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
        },
        body:JSON.stringify({"name":name})
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => console.log(data.result) )

}
```

Trying this code I saw the following errors in my console:

```
DELETE http://127.0.0.1:8000/deleteFavourite/ 404 (Not Found)
Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON
Promise.then (async)
```

I successfully managed to add objects using POST request but failed to delete objects using DELETE method. Can anyone kindly  tell me have I forgotten to do certain thing or done something wrong?

Comment: can you share your urls please?

Comment: The Post is updated with adding urls.py

Comment: Does it matter that your urls.py has `path('deleteFavourite', views.deleteFavourites)` without the trailing `/` at the end of the path, and the others have it? I haven't used Django in quite some time but I remember some of that being tricky.

Comment: Thank you so much. Yes, that was the point.

Answer (score 0):

Thank to [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/users/8678978/chrisbyte I remembered that we should wrap the end of url with a slash. So my **urls.py** should be like this:

```
     **urlpatterns = [
                  path('deleteFavourite/', views.deleteFavourites),
                    ]**
```